# How to integrate PayUMoney payments for paying from merchant account to any user's bank account?

Tags: python, payment-gateway, payment-processing, payumoney, payu

I am making a website with **python** using **django** where I would reward user with money.

I want to integrate **PayUMoney** payment gateway in a way that I could pay any user I want the money with the details they provide.

How do I end up doing that?
I have experience of integrating **PayUMoney** to allow user to pay to merchant.

Comment: Show us whatever you have tried pls

Comment: @DineshKumar I have integrated following steps in this documentation for [python](https://developer.payumoney.com/webkits/)